# TCP number of connections differ from client to server

Tags: linux, java, tcp, netstat

How can this be ? netstat shows x 'established' connections from the client to y 'established' connections on the server. Situation stays like this  for 10 minutes, then x and y change, then another 10 minutes of stability and so on. Eventually x will equal y many many hours after the experiment has begun, but not the expected value anyway.

Should it matter, client side is a java program, server side is native code. Both ubuntu linuxes. Oh and needless to say, the experiment is a failure.

Comment: What does the network in between consist of?  How are the connection counts differing? i.e: is X always => Y (or vice versa)? Are you also checking the server's netstat? Are you expecting a certain amount of connections?

Comment: network in between ... at least 100 Mbps link ? x >= y usually but I have seen it the other way around too. netstat is the tool that got me these odd results, yes. Should be a certain number of connections indeed.

Comment: Are you ever exceeding the expected number of connections?  I asked about the network in between as routing and caching may cause some unexpected results, so I was looking for information about the physical network setup. :) Like, do you get the same results if you directly wire the client machine to the server?

Comment: I see. I am afraid I can not test such setup. At least not momentarilly. Will keep that in mind though.

Answer (score 3):

If one side closes the connection without signaling that it will be closing you will be left with a [Half Open](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-33) connection.

Intentionally closing only one side of the connection is the way old [SYN Flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) Denial of Service attacks where performed.

Comment: interesting read. But how is it that they take so long (hours) to get in sync again (if it really happens, I am not really betting a cookie on this). And why do they never end up in the same place as started (x = 20) ? Perhaps there are some sys variables to be adjusting on linux for TCP timeouts ?

Comment: Maybe you have a program that is constantly dropping connections, and once every few hours it behaves correctly and you have no half open connections. You really need to look at what the [connection state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) is of those 20 connections are.

Comment: as described, the connections are all in the 'established' state. I can spot in 1 % of my readings 'time_wait' states (only on client side) but I guess that is the only normal part in this mess.

Comment: I did not realize that when you said "netstat shows x established connections from the client to y established connections" you where actually referring to the `ESTABLISHED` connection state, not that you just saw that many items listed in netstat.